# Lookup function in Dax

Tags: powerbi, dax

How can I create a DAX (calculated field) to perform a lookup from table 1 to table 2 in Power pivot as below?

1. Customer Table (Dimension)

| Customer Key | FirstPurchaseDate |
| --- | --- |
| 10000 | 9/7/2018 |
| 10001 | 28/7/2018 |
| 10002 | 9/9/2021 |

2. Sales Table (Fact)

| Customer Key | Order Date | FirstPurchaseDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10000 | 9/7/2019 |  |
| 10000 | 28/7/2019 |  |
| 10001 | 9/10/2019 |  |
| 10003 | 9/10/2019 |  |

Both tables have customer key as primary key with 1-many relationship. I've try related, relatedtable and lookupvalue but fail.

Thanks a lot for your help !!

Comment: Can you show in image? It is quite hard to see how the data look like, probably also what is the expected output

Comment: Do the tables have a relationship? What is the reason for duplicating an existing column to another table?

Comment: Oh, Sales table didn't have, and will not have a physical First purchase date, I want to do it in measure (calculated field) as reference for another measure.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a calculated column with the `LOOKUPVALUE` DAX function in the sales tables, it worked for me. Try the following DAX and if it helps then mark it as the answer.

`First Order Date = LOOKUPVALUE(Table1[FPD], Table1[Customer Key], Table2[Cutomer Key])`

[image: Output and Input]

Also, you use the `LOOKUPVALUE` function for checking the conditions from multiple tables.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comments. I understand I can do this via calculated column, but I want to do it in calculated field.

Comment: Both tables have customer key as relationship, 1 to many, active. I've try Related function, but the error claims there's no relationship between the 2 tables when i place them in pivot. I've also try lookupvalue, which of course work in calculated column, but there's an error in dax as well.

Comment: Regarding the error in the Related function, it's maybe because the columns you are using in a relationship don't support that, so you need to check on that. About the error in DAX, can you post your function here? Also, can you post a picture of input and the relationship modeling and the errors you are getting with all the DAX functions so that it's easy to figure out the issue.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

with your sample data, simple `RELATED` function is all you need, given you have established a relationship `Sales:Customer - (Many:One)` and made this relationship `Active`, then with simple `FirstPurchaseDate = RELATED(Customer[FirstPurchaseDate])`, you have your working solution.

[See the solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETDpA.png)

If you experience any issues, please post your exact error messages.